# How to point my domain directly to a codeignter folder?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Let's say I have a domain [www.example.com](https://www.example.com)

Now I want that, at this domain, my index page or main controller of the CodeIgniter folder should open **without the folder name** and the rest controller pages also without the folder name.

```
From: www.example.com/folder 
To: www.example.com
```

I am hosting my files on hostinger. I don't want to remove my folder and export all the structure to base `public_html`.

I want my `public_html` to contain my CodeIgniter folder.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't your hosting provide offer a means to alter the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of your host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup codeigniter on a subdirectory, you could try the following *htaccess* rule :

```sh
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /YOUR_SUBFOLDER

RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Change the `YOUR_SUBFOLDER` above to whatever subdirectory name you have.